# Swift Выделить область изображения перед отправкой

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Задача: есть изображение которое будет парситься на сервере в текст, перед отправкой изображения нужно что бы пользователь пальцем закрасил область которая будет отправлена на сервер.
Возможно область изображения которую не выделили будет вырезаться или просто закрашиваться. Видел реализацию например у гугл переводчика. Подскажите в какую сторону копать. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

- закрашивать/выделять пальцем - использовать `touchesBegan`/`touchesEnded` либо `UITapGestureRecognizer` для определения начальной/конечной позиции пальца и области для закрашивания/выделения
- обрезать/закрашивать области - методы CoreGraphics (например `CGImageCreateWithImageInRect`), `UIBezierPath`

Comment: Подучится обрезка прямоугольником? Или можно фигурно?

Comment: @Konstantin можно и фигурно, используя маску, например https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22985171/image-masking-create-new-uiimage